# Contains() inside a Where() is not returning results - Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I am having trouble with a bit of linq. I am trying to get a list of objects that is trimmed down if the particular Id is contained in my list of Ids. This is the code example:

```
public IServiceResult<List<SurveyAnswer>> GetSurveyProjectSite(List<Guid>spsQsIds)
{

    return this.Wrap(() =>
    {

        this.InspectionContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        List<SurveyProjectSiteQuestionResponse> response = new List<SurveyProjectSiteQuestionResponse>();
        List<SurveyAnswer> answers = new List<SurveyAnswer>();

        var newList = this.InspectionContext.SurveyProjectSiteQuestionResponses
            .Include("SurveyAnswer")
            .Where(x => spsQsIds.Contains(x.SurveyProjectSiteQuestionSetId));

        response.AddRange(newList);

        foreach (SurveyProjectSiteQuestionResponse r in response)
        {
            answers.Add(r.SurveyAnswer);
        }

        return answers;
    });
}
```

Class:

```
public class SurveyProjectSiteQuestionResponse : IDentifiable<Guid>, IPushable, IPullable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Guid SurveyProjectSiteQuestionSetId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SurveyProjectSiteQuestionSetId")]
    public virtual SurveyProjectSiteQuestionSet SurveyProjectSiteQuestionSet { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public long SurveyQuestionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SurveyQuestionId")]
    public virtual SurveyQuestion SurveyQuestion { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public Guid SurveyAnswerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SurveyAnswerId")]
    public virtual SurveyAnswer SurveyAnswer { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ResponseDate { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(7)]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

}
```

The problem exists in the Where(). When I have the Contains() in it, I don't get any results back. I have checked my Guids and there are 77 matches for the instance I was testing. Is there something that is preventing the Contains() from working right in the Where() as I have it written. Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: If you're asking about LINQ, you *need* to post the classes you're querying into.

Comment: And look in the SQL Profiler (or MiniProfiler http://miniprofiler.com/) to see what query is sent and whether it contains the correct parameters.

Comment: Guid correctly implements IEquatable<Guid> ... so it should work fine as it is

Comment: therefore the problem is either in the way Linq to Entities translates this or elsewhere